# Why does pylint check for member which are not in __slots__ when assigning but not when accessing?

Tags: python, pylint

When assigning an attribute not in the **slots** pylint raises the error E0237': Assigning to attribute not defined in class slots'

However it does not when accessing an attribute not in **slots**

See example below.

Is it a "missing feature" or is there a reason not to check it?

```
class Dummyclass(object):

    __slots__ = ['myvariable']

    def __init__(self):
        self.myvariable = 1

def main():
    dummy = Dummyclass()

    dummy.doesnotexist = 4 #This raises an error
    temp = dummy.doesnotexist #This does not
```

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError`s for both `dummy.doesnotexist = 4` and `temp = dummy.doesnotexist`

Comment: @jDo: I'm getting the error at runtime, but not when editing using pydev + pylint and pycharm. I have to use this for tests which last a few hours. I need to detect them before runtime.

Comment: Ok, I didn't try it with pylint but just executed different variations of the code and got errors in both cases.I'm not sure what pylint does differently

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I have edited the file python_dir\Lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\classes.py by adding the command:
self._check_in_slots(node) in visit attribute. 
It now checks correctly the access as well as the assignation.